# Ideas/Assistance with ActionScript Color Fading?

Tags: javascript, actionscript

Here is a function I added to my Flash-based chat to rainbowify certain text within [rainbow] and [/rainbow] tags.

```
ChatUI.prototype.rainbowParse = function(txt) {
    txt = txt;
    if ((txt.indexOf("[rainbow]") > -1) && (txt.indexOf("[/rainbow]") > -1)) {
        txt = txt.replace("&apos;", "@").replace("&amp;apos;", "@");
        var firstChar = txt.indexOf("[rainbow]") + 9;
        var lastChar = txt.indexOf("[/rainbow]");

        if (((lastChar - firstChar) > 100) || ((txt.split("[rainbow]").length - 1) > 3)) {
            break;
        }

        while (lastChar <= txt.lastIndexOf("[/rainbow]")) {
            var RAINBOWTEXT = '';
            var i = firstChar;
            while (i < lastChar) {
                RAINBOWTEXT += txt.charAt(i);
                i++
            }
            var text = RAINBOWTEXT;
            var texty = '';

            colors = new Array('ff00ff','ff00cc','ff0099','ff0066','ff0033','ff0000','ff3300','ff6600','ff9900','ffcc00','ffff00','ccff00','99ff00','66ff00','33ff00','00ff00','00ff33','00ff66','00ff99','00ffcc','00ffff','00ccff','0099ff','0066ff','0033ff','0000ff','3300ff','6600ff','9900ff','cc00ff');

            i = 0;

            while (i <= text.length) {
                var t = text.charAt(i);

                if (t != undefined) {
                    texty += "<font color=\"#" + colors[i % colors.length] + "\">" + t + "</font>";
                    i++;
                }
            }

            texty = texty.replace("> <", ">&nbsp;<");
            var REPLACEME = "[rainbow]" + RAINBOWTEXT + "[/rainbow]";
            txt = txt.replace(REPLACEME, texty);

            if (lastChar == txt.lastIndexOf("[/rainbow]")) {
                break;
            }
            nextChar = lastChar + 10;
            firstChar = txt.indexOf("[rainbow]", lastChar) + 9;
            lastChar = txt.indexOf("[/rainbow]", lastChar);
        }
        txt = txt.replace("@", "&apos;");
    }
    return txt;
}
```

However, I don't like this way these rainbows look. The text's colors repeat themselves.

To see an example of what I mean, go to http://www.tektek.org/color/ and click "Rainbow" and preview with the repeat set to 1. Then preview with it set to 3 or higher.

I want my code to have a repeat of 1, but since the rainbow text length varies so much, I have no idea how to do this. I've Googled numerous rainbow text generators, trying to look at their code. It sucks. Please give me some ideas or assistance with this. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to divide the number of elements in your colors array by the number of characters in your rainbow string and apply each colour to that number of characters in your string. That way each color will be applied only once and in equal proportions regardless of the length of your string:

```
// Calculate the number of characters to apply each character to
var inc = Math.round(colors.length / txt.length);
// Empty string to store the modified rainbox text in
var str = ""; 
// Loop through each color and apply it to the correct number of characters
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i ++) {
    str += "<font color='#'" + colors[i] + "'>" 
        + txt.substr(i * inc, inc)
        + "</font>";
}
```

**Edit:**

Okay, I reread the question and looked again at the example you link to and I think a better solution would be to create a linear gradient in a `Sprite` using the drawing API and mask it using the text field containing the text which must have the rainbow effect applied to it:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.GradientType;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.text.Font;

// You need to embed the font to use it as a mask 
Font.registerFont(Arial);

var txt:String = "My Rainbow text";

// Removed some of your colors to save time formatting
var colors:Array = [0xff00ff, 0xff00cc, 0xff0099, 0xff0066, 0xff0033, 
                    0xff0000, 0xff3300, 0xff6600, 0xff9900, 0xffcc00, 
                    0xffff00, 0xccff00, 0x99ff00, 0x66ff00, 0x33ff00];

var alphas:Array = [];
var ratios:Array = [];

// Populate alphas and ratios arrays of the same length as colors array
for (var i:int = 0; i < colors.length; i ++)
{
    alphas.push(1); 
    ratios.push(i * Math.round(255 / colors.length)); // Equal ratio for each color
}

// Create a text field
var field:TextField = new TextField();
field.text = txt;
field.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
field.setTextFormat(new TextFormat("Arial", 30, 0x0000000));
field.embedFonts = true;

// Create a gradient of the same dimensions as the text field
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.createGradientBox(field.width, field.height);

var gradient:Sprite = new Sprite();
gradient.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, colors, alphas, ratios, matrix);
gradient.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, field.width, field.height);
gradient.graphics.endFill();

this.addChild(field);
this.addChild(gradient);

// Mask the gradient with the text field
gradient.mask = field;
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking something like that, however I didn't know how to implement it. What happens if the string is an odd number? I guess one way I could fix that would be to check the count of the string and if it's odd, add a space to the end of the string... that might work.

Comment: Well, I've integrated it with my function. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BYrknQXW is what I got and I have been testing this on http://jsfiddle.net/ to save compile time, but I can't get it to output anything.

Comment: Sorry Dav, I just updated my answer! I think the second approach is probably much closer to what you want. The first one fails if you have fewer characters in your rainbow string than colors.